Vega Lite: Is there a way to have two layers on a folded graph
I'm using this as my reference - Link to Fold Example
I'd like to not only have the bar chart but have another layer that shows the data labels too. (Like this - https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/examples/layer_bar_labels.html)
Thanks for your help.
I tried adding a layer component with both a "bar" and "text" layer but it combines both folded columns.


{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {"country": "USA", "gold": 10, "silver": 20},
      {"country": "Canada", "gold": 7, "silver": 26}
    ]
  },
  "transform": [{"fold": ["gold", "silver"]}],
  "facet": {"column": {"field": "key"}},
  "spec": {
    "layer": [
      {
        "mark": "bar",
        "encoding": {
          "x": {"field": "country", "type": "nominal"},
          "y": {"field": "value", "type": "quantitative"},
          "color": {"field": "country", "type": "nominal"}
        }
      },
      {
        "mark": {"type": "text", "dy": -4},
        "encoding": {
          "text": {"field": "value", "type": "quantitative"},
          "x": {"field": "country", "type": "nominal"},
          "y": {"field": "value", "type": "quantitative"}
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}

